# Visualforce Page using wrong data for updates

Tags: visualforce

I am facing a weird problem in my Visualforce page. We have a inventory management system that has a list of the parts and the orders associated to that parts showing on the visualforce page. I created a wrapper class to display this entire list on the page with a checkbox next to each row. Uses can adjust values in the row like quantity(Inline edit) and select the checkbox for the rows they want to process and hit the submit button. In the background I am creating tracking records for the processed records and sending out an email notification. The issue is: The users are opening the page and leaving it open for an hour or more, without refreshing the screen, they are coming back and selecting rows and hitting submit button. And wrong rows are being processed meaning on page load if the display shows row 1,row2 actual button click is processing row3 and row4. Not sure what exactly is happening. Can some one help me find the issue please?

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <apex:commandButton style="background-color:#D9534F;padding:6px 12px;" styleClass="btn btn-danger hovery" action="{!releaseRecordsAction}" value="Release" onComplete="sendEmail()" status="loadStatus" />
    <apex:actionFunction id="sendEmail" action="{!emailReleaseRecords}" name="sendEmail"> </apex:actionFunction>
</div>
<tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!releaseRecords}" var="release">
        <tr class="dataRows">
            <td title="PO #">
                <apex:commandLink value="{!release.poline.PO_Header__r.PO_number__c}" action="{!processLinkClick}" target="_blank">
```

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help you if you post the markup and code you already have so we have something to refer to :) Hard to diagnose a problem without seeing what could be the cause.

Comment: <div class="col-md-2">
                            <apex:commandButton style="background-color:#D9534F;padding:6px 12px;" styleClass="btn btn-danger hovery"  action="{!releaseRecordsAction}" value="Release" onComplete="sendEmail()" status="loadStatus"/>
                            <apex:actionFunction id="sendEmail" action="{!emailReleaseRecords}" name="sendEmail">
                            </apex:actionFunction>
                        </div>

Comment: <tbody>  <apex:repeat value="{!releaseRecords}" var="release">
                                        <tr class="dataRows">
                                            <td title="PO #">
                                                <apex:commandLink value="{!release.poline.PO_Header__r.PO_number__c}" action="{!processLinkClick}" target="_blank">

Comment: How do i add the complete class/page?

Comment: Hi Scorpio ,Welcome to SFSE !!! you can edit your question, and after pasting code, you can use code formating tool available on stack exchange.